# Can't get wordpress feed to display full article

Tags: wordpress

This is probably going to be a really simple fix... I just can't figure it out.

I want to display the posts from a wordpress category on the following page: http://www.oe-design.com/about-press.php?test

I've managed to do so but when I show the 'description' on the page (my code: $item->description), it only shows a snippet of the article, not the full article...

What do I need to use to show the full article?

I am trying to view the wordpress RSS feed but when I view it in FireFox it asks me to subscribe so I can't actually view it and see what I need to do to view the full article. Safari shows their own custom feed layout...

Hopefully I am making sense

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your feed doesn't have anything to do with displaying the full article or the excerpt on your category page. Change `<?php the_excerpt();?>` to `<?php the_content();?>` in your theme files, like category.pgp, single.php, etc.

Comment: Also see the first four questions here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Layout_and_Design#Text_and_Content_Display